# pip dependenciy conflict- penylane

Tags: pip, protocol-buffers, version, conflict

I am getting this error, can you tell me what I should do? Thanks!

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

pennylane-sf 0.29.1 requires pennylane=0.19, but you have pennylane 0.31.0 which is incompatible.
cirq-google 1.1.0 requires protobuf=3.15.0, but you have protobuf 4.23.3 which is incompatible.
paddle-quantum 2.4.0 requires protobuf=3.1.0, but you have protobuf 4.23.3 which is incompatible.
```

google search, but was not able to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The [pennylane-sf plugin page](https://pypi.org/project/PennyLane-SF/) says:

> This plugin will not be supported in newer versions of Pennylane. It is compatible with versions of PennyLane up to and including 0.29

If you really want to get it installed, you must first install older version of pennylane. In simple case this could go by:

```
 pip install --force-reinstall pennylane=0.29.1
```

but there may be further packages that you need to downgrade also.

**Be sure to do this inside a [Python virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/), to avoid messing up system package installations.**